# how to enable the radio button depending on the data coming from web services?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

here i had implemented a custom design like the image [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krRKz.png) i need to active the radio button depending on my web services data. In web services one key value pair i was receiving 0 & 1 only in that if it is 1 then i need to make active the radio button any help how to implement ?

here is the code for my radio button

```
        @IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
            let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)
            let checkIndex = self.checkIsButtonEnable.index(of: sender.tag)
            if sender.isSelected {

            } else{
                if(chekIndex == nil){
                    self.checkIsRadioSelect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.checkIsRadioSelect.append(sender.tag)
                    self.checkIsButtonEnable.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.checkIsButtonEnable.append(sender.tag)
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

here is the code for table view

```
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! addressTableViewCell
                tableDetails.isHidden = false
                myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                let arr = detailsArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"]as? String
                cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
                let mobilenumber : Int =  arr["number"] as! Int
                cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = String(describing: mobilenumber)
                let defaultaddress : Int = arr["default"] as! Int
                cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.editButton.isHidden = true
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
                let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
                if(checkIndex != nil){
                    cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
                    cell.editButton.isHidden = false
                    cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
                }else{
                    cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
                    cell.editButton.isHidden = true
                    cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
                }
                return cell
```

Comment: I didn't get from you whether you need to show the state of radio button using the API data. Or you wanna update the radio button state while clicking  it?

Comment: i need to have both but for first time app loading then it should get from api and make active the radio button depending on my data and later on i need to change it manually

Comment: for manually i had already set and i need to set the api data also @DSDharma

Comment: check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line of code.

```
let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row) //delete this line

let checkIndex = arr["default"] as! Int //use radio button key.

@IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {

        let arr = detailsArray[sender.tag]
        if sender.isSelected {
            arr["default"] = @"0"

        } else{
            arr["default"] = @"1"
        }
        self.tableDetails.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: i am not getting radiobuttonkey as keyvalue pair then how it works

Comment: i am getting default as keyvalue pair for that i need to set to radiobutton

Comment: let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)   i am using this for manual changing of radio button key to active

Comment: what is the key? can you share web service response.

Comment: default is my keyvalue

Comment: for the first time my app loads at that time i need to display the radio button active for depending on default key value pair later on i need to change manually so i was using that code

Comment: Can you share weservcie response?

Comment: {
  "address": [
    {
      "default": 0, 
      "address": "No:11/111 ,cross street,Nungambakkam,mylapore,chennai :600088", 
      "number": 9123456711, 
      "name": "Ramesh"
    }, 
    {
      "default": 1, 
      "address": "No:22/222 ,cross street,Perambur,chennai :600012", 
      "number": 8123456722, 
      "name": "Vignesh"
    }, 
    {
      "default": 0, 
      "address": "No:33/333 ,cross street,Villivakkam,chennai :600045", 
      "number": 7123456733, 
      "name": "Rajesh"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: here is my web service response

Comment: let checkIndex = arr["default"] as! Int

Comment: but without removing the code what u said can i able to change it ?

Comment: on button action change default value in detailsArray. it will work as you expected

Comment: where u mentioned i didn't get it ?

Comment: Give more details about the issue.

Comment: for the first time app loads at that time the radio button should active depending on the web services data and need to change manually after loading the app @SP74

Comment: Handle user button actions and update your detailsArray object with proper values.

Comment: how to update the details array with the buttton actions @SP74 ?

Comment: let arr = detailsArray[sender.tag]
        if sender.isSelected {
            arr["default"] = @"0"

        } else{
            arr["default"] = @"1"
        }

Comment: it didn't work it is making active all the radio buttons @SP74

Comment: get last active record and make this as deactivate.

Comment: only one should active after loading an app but here all the radio buttons are active

Comment: check the Webservice response and bool value in cell for row

Comment: according to web service only second radio button need to be active but here all are becoming active when i run the app

Comment: Print checkIndex value in console .

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method update code like below

My suggestion is Don't set indexPath.row as tag while reusing tableView cells it won't give you better result.Make some unique id as tag. or do some math calculation something adding/multiplying with numbers.

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! addressTableViewCell
 tableDetails.isHidden = false
 myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
 let arr = detailsArray[indexPath.row]
 cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"]as? String
 cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
 let mobilenumber : Int =  arr["number"] as! Int
 cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = String(describing: mobilenumber)
 cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
 cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
 cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
 cell.editButton.isHidden = true
 cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
 cell.radioButton.isSelected = false

 if let isDefault = arr["default"] as? Bool { // i think it won't be Integer it will be Bool,please debug & check it
          cell.radioButton.isSelected = isDefault 
          cell.editButton.isHidden = false
          cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
 }
 let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
     if(checkIndex != nil){
     cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
     cell.editButton.isHidden = false
     cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
  }
```

Comment: i need to replace or to add it there in that method

Comment: replace your old  code for radio button with it.Make sure to check the default value is Bool or Int

Comment: that means i need to replace it in radio button action method or cell for row at indexpth

Comment: Yes and i don't know the use of self.checkIsRadioSelect plz update of it

Comment: if i change then i am unable to update the radio button active manually

Comment: Problem it is..where you are used your defaultaddress value ? You only conditioned for checking index of array not value from API

Comment: i need to have both that is i need to change manually and i need to get from api and set radio button active depending on it when app loaded first time

Comment: Then  add one more condition to check whether array have value or not.

Comment: how to check another condition ?